# Why we using inf and power in the matlab code

Tags: matlab

I am using the following code in the Matlab, confusion is why we using `inf` here and why we need `power(2,14:28)` and later we using size with in size.

```
gpu = gpuDevice();
fprintf('Using a %s GPU.\n', gpu.Name)
sizeOfDouble = 8; % Each double-precision number needs 8 bytes of storage
sizes = power(2, 14:28);
sendTimes = inf(size(sizes));
gatherTimes = inf(size(sizes));
```

I am new to Matlab here, trying to understand this code. [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/measuring-gpu-performance.html) is the source of code

Comment: I'm very certain that this code is using Infinity (`inf` built-in function) as a placeholder for values that aren't known yet.

Comment: @Ben great thank you, why we using `power(2,14:28)` , is it the value coming from gpu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

power(2,14:28) is just the verbose way of computing element-wise power 2.^(14:28), which is shorthand for creating the vector of values [2^14,2^15,...,2^28].

The inf(size(sizes)) is just code for pre-allocating a double array the same size as what the power(etc.) call produced with all values initialized to inf. Presumably downstream in the code these inf values will be replaced with some other values.

*EDIT for downstream code:*

If you look at how the variable sizes is used downstream in the code:

```
numElements = sizes(ii)/sizeOfDouble;
hostData = randi([0 9], numElements, 1);
gpuData = randi([0 9], numElements, 1, 'gpuArray');
```

You can see that it is simply used for the number of elements of other variables. That is, the test will be run with various sized variables to see the timing implications, and the sizes variable is used to generate the number of elements for variables used in a particular iteration of the test.

Comment: element-wise power? why we need that? any source for that? I updated the question with the source of code

Comment: @AHF: Notice that page has a log-log plot where the x axis is "size in bytes".  These powers of 2 are the various x values used for that plot.

Comment: just a very last question, why its starting from 14? why not from 1 or 2 or 8 ?

Comment: @AHF Because whoever wrote that code thought that 14 was a good start point. Many choices are arbitrary, not everything has an obvious, unique explanation.